# Как выравнивать элементы в html?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, только учусь писать странички и столкнулся с проблемой: 
1. Как сделать так , чтобы ячейки формы выровнены вместе с кнопкой? Как это делать вообще для элементов? 
2. Как сделать чтобы картинка была ровно посередине кнопки? 
В данный момент это выглядит как-то так:
[image: Данные Формы]

Фрагмент кода:

```html
<form>
  <p><input type="button" value="Добавить процесс теплообмена"></p>
  <p>
    <input name="c" placeholder="c">
    <input name="m" placeholder="m">
    <input name="t" placeholder="t">
    <input name="t0" placeholder="t0">
    <button> 
    <img src="Pictures\cogwheel-112226.png"> 
   </button>
  </p>

  <p><input type="button" value="Добавить изменение агрегатного состояния"></p>

  <p>
    <input name="Lamb" placeholder="λ">
    <input name="m" placeholder="m">
    <button style="width:20px;height:20px"> 
    <img src="Pictures\cogwheel-112226.png"> 
   </button>
  </p>

  <p><input type="submit" value="Подтвердить"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: дайте html и css Вашей страницы (в редакторе: Фрагмент кода)

Answer (score 4):

1. Самый простой вариант вертикального выравнивания. Можно отцентрировать элементы по вертикали относительно друг друга, поставив им всем значение `vertical-align: middle;`

   p * {
   vertical-align: middle;
   }

Насчет вариантов вертикального выравнивания есть целая статья https://habrahabr.ru/company/netcracker/blog/277433/

Дальше как выровнять картинку на кнопке если указать фиксированные размеры.

2. Если задать фиксированные размеры кнопке, то у неё внутри ещё есть граница и отступы и картинка вставится после них (к примеру у меня в браузере 2 пикселя границы и 6px отступы слева и справа). Поэтому проще всего позиционировать картинку относительно кнопки с помощью `position:absolute`. Если кнопка гораздо больше картинки или у нее не заданы размеры, то картинка итак спозиционируется по центру. Еще можно уменьшить внутренние отступы кнопки указав `padding:0`.
3. Так как позиционирование относительно кнопки работает не от угла кнопки, а от угла границы, то стоит сделать обертку вокруг кнопки `<span class="wrap">...</span>` и позиционировать относительно нее. Теперь будет неважно какие размеры границы задал браузер кнопке.

```css
p * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mybutton {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.mybutton svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.wrap button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.wrap button svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input name="Lamb" placeholder="λ">
  <button style="padding:2px;">
    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M20 13.44v-2.88l-1.8-.3c-.1-.397-.3-.794-.6-1.39l1.1-1.49-2.1-2.088-1.5 1.093c-.5-.298-1-.497-1.4-.596L13.5 4h-2.9l-.3 1.79c-.5.098-.9.297-1.4.595L7.4 5.292 5.3 7.38l1 1.49c-.3.496-.4.894-.6 1.39l-1.7.2v2.882l1.8.298c.1.497.3.894.6 1.39l-1 1.492 2.1 2.087 1.5-1c.4.2.9.395 1.4.594l.3 1.79h3l.3-1.79c.5-.1.9-.298 1.4-.596l1.5 1.092 2.1-2.08-1.1-1.49c.3-.496.5-.993.6-1.39l1.5-.3zm-8 1.492c-1.7 0-3-1.292-3-2.982 0-1.69 1.3-2.98 3-2.98s3 1.29 3 2.98-1.3 2.982-3 2.982z"/>
    </svg>
  </button>
</p>
<p>
  <input name="Lamb" placeholder="λ" style="vertical-align:middle;">
  <button class="mybutton">
    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M20 13.44v-2.88l-1.8-.3c-.1-.397-.3-.794-.6-1.39l1.1-1.49-2.1-2.088-1.5 1.093c-.5-.298-1-.497-1.4-.596L13.5 4h-2.9l-.3 1.79c-.5.098-.9.297-1.4.595L7.4 5.292 5.3 7.38l1 1.49c-.3.496-.4.894-.6 1.39l-1.7.2v2.882l1.8.298c.1.497.3.894.6 1.39l-1 1.492 2.1 2.087 1.5-1c.4.2.9.395 1.4.594l.3 1.79h3l.3-1.79c.5-.1.9-.298 1.4-.596l1.5 1.092 2.1-2.08-1.1-1.49c.3-.496.5-.993.6-1.39l1.5-.3zm-8 1.492c-1.7 0-3-1.292-3-2.982 0-1.69 1.3-2.98 3-2.98s3 1.29 3 2.98-1.3 2.982-3 2.982z"/>
    </svg>
  </button>
</p>
<p>
  <input name="Lamb" placeholder="λ" style="vertical-align:middle;">
  <span class="wrap">
    <button>
      <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M20 13.44v-2.88l-1.8-.3c-.1-.397-.3-.794-.6-1.39l1.1-1.49-2.1-2.088-1.5 1.093c-.5-.298-1-.497-1.4-.596L13.5 4h-2.9l-.3 1.79c-.5.098-.9.297-1.4.595L7.4 5.292 5.3 7.38l1 1.49c-.3.496-.4.894-.6 1.39l-1.7.2v2.882l1.8.298c.1.497.3.894.6 1.39l-1 1.492 2.1 2.087 1.5-1c.4.2.9.395 1.4.594l.3 1.79h3l.3-1.79c.5-.1.9-.298 1.4-.596l1.5 1.092 2.1-2.08-1.1-1.49c.3-.496.5-.993.6-1.39l1.5-.3zm-8 1.492c-1.7 0-3-1.292-3-2.982 0-1.69 1.3-2.98 3-2.98s3 1.29 3 2.98-1.3 2.982-3 2.982z"/>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос конечно не полон. Но если правильно понял - выравнивание можете сделать с помощью `margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;` смотря что у Вас в разметке и стилях. Картинка по середине попробуйте так - для самой кнопки, где нужна картинка пишем css - `background:url('путь до картинки')center no-repeat;`